# Is there a better way to construct such a priority queue?

Tags: tree, functional-programming, ocaml, priority-queue

I have implemented a priority queue, it works well. What follows is my type definition.

```
type 'a t = | Leaf of ('a -> 'a -> int)
            | Node of 'a * 'a t * 'a t * ('a -> 'a -> int)
```

My idea is that the tree takes a comparator function ('a -> 'a -> int) and produces an 'a t, which would be sorted by the comparator.
However, I have the comparator on every Leaf and Node, and I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.
Specifically, given a tree, I want to be able to access its comparator easily. And I don't know whether I could do this without having the comparator on every Node and Leaf of my tree.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard approach to this problem is to write a functor that given
a module that includes the type contained in your PQ + the comparison
function you've given returns a new PQ module specialized for that type
and comparison function.

```
module PriorityQueue (OT : Map.OrderedType) = struct
  type t = 
    | Leaf
    | Node of OT.t * t * t
  (*Define your functions in terms of OT.compare ...*)
end
```

You would then create a concrete PriorityQueue module with

```
module FunnyPQ = PriorityQueue(struct
  type t = int
  let compare _ _ = pred (Random.int 3)
end)
```

See definition for OrderedType:http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Map.OrderedType.html

You can of course also use the approach you've taken but factor out
the data type into 2 types the following way

```
type 'a pq = 
  | Leaf
  | Node of 'a * 'a pq * 'a pq

type 'a t = { 
  comp : 'a -> 'a -> int ;
  pq : 'a pq
}
```

note that you lose some type safety with this approach because now if you're writing a function with for example a signature like `'a pq -> 'a pq -> 'a pq` You cannot guarantee that the first pq argument and second pq argument were constructed with the same comparison function.

Comment: Functors do work, but I think a comparator function already indicates the type of the tree, so I would prefer not creating a functor with both the type and function.

Comment: I think there might be a problem with your code. In the second definition, your pq requires 'a t be defined first, in 'a t, pq needs to be defined first. I could not define the types in your way.

Comment: The definitions were not meant to be interdependent. This is commensurable with his comment regarding using a different comparator function than the one originally used to construct the tree.

Comment: @nlucaroni : Sorry, but I do want the comparators to be consistent in one tree. The only way for users to provide the comparator is by constructing a Leaf as a base case.

Comment: @didierc : I don't know whether it is worth it to add such an independent structure. Now the edited 'a t seems to be a good structure. I'll try it.

Comment: @didierc noted. corrected my answer to reflect the actual problem.